# Is there an online bash script testing site?

Tags: bash

Sometimes I need to assist friends with bash scripting. When I'm on a Windows machine, it's a working environment and I can't just setup Cygwin or use a VM.

Is there some free scripting website I can use, preferably where I can use Putty to connect it or something similar?

Comment: I ran across [ideone](http://ideone.com/about), an interesting site, in the past.  I haven't used it much nor can I vouch for its accuracy or POSIX compliance or usefulness, but it does include `bash` version 4 as one of the languages you can supposedly test online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a heavy weight solution, you can spin up an Amazon EC2 instance.  The "free/trial" tier is free for the first year of your account:

http://aws.amazon.com/free/

So, in that case, you'll have a wide choice of distros and shells to play with.

Comment: This is a bit overkill for just testing - there are many online sites where you can paste and run shell scripts. Also while this wasn't an option when the OP asked his question, in 2017 there was already WSL1 which is a very convenient way to get a lightweight linux shell in Windows (now superseded by WSL2).

Answer (score 7):

I believe you are looking for a "[free shell account](http://shells.red-pill.eu/)". You should be able to sign up for one that has a description of what you are looking for.

These are typically provided with no expectation of privacy. Be careful what you store and what passwords you use.

Answer (score 6):

The #bash channel on [freenode](https://freenode.net/) recommends [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/), an online resource where you can paste your shell scripts and they will be checked for syntax errors, POSIX compliance and other straightforward errors:

> ShellCheck is a static analysis and linting tool for sh/bash scripts. It's mainly focused on handling typical beginner and intermediate level syntax errors and pitfalls where the shell just gives a cryptic error message or strange behavior, but it also reports on a few more advanced issues where corner cases can cause delayed failures.

ShellCheck is an [open source project](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), so you can download the code and run your own instance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this website, you can use the CLI as well as create `.sh` files and run them: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php

Answer (score 0):

If you seek something or somewhere that you can execute Linux and bash commands http://cb.vu/ seems to be a good place. This is a web based shell.

Comment: This is not a `bash` (or even POSIX resemblant) shell in any sense.

Comment: This is at least somewhere this you can enter some linux commands and see what happens, isn't it?

Comment: When it's at the point that one gets `if: Command not found`, shell redirection operators don't work, and almost none of the commands match the functionality of their standard equivalents (not to mention they appear to not even be trying to mimic Linux, mentioning FreeBSD in their quasi-MOTD)...

Comment: This is not a bash shell, so it does not fit the OP requirements. It has a very small subset of specific commands. It is not suitable for scripting.